# Galois group question (involving the primitive n-th root of unity)

Tags: galois-theory

Suppose $\gamma$ is the primitive n-th root of unity.  That is, $\gamma = e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{n}}$.  I have to find the subgroup of $G(\mathbb{Q}(\gamma)/\mathbb{Q})$ that fixes the field $\mathbb{Q}(\gamma + \gamma^{-1})$.

I know that $G(\mathbb{Q}(\gamma)/\mathbb{Q})$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$ and that it contains $\phi(n)$ distinct elements.  However I'm not sure if what I'm doing is the correct approach.

I know that my elements in the Galois group will be the following:

$\iota$ - the identity map, which fixes everything.

$\sigma_i$ - the map that sends $\gamma$ to $\gamma^i$, for $1 \leq i \leq n-1$

What I did next is take an arbitrary element of $\mathbb{Q}(\gamma)$, say $a_0 + a_1\gamma + a_2\gamma^2 + ... + a_{n-1}\gamma^{n-1}$ and put it through the various automorphisms.  But I'm sort of worried that the way I defined my automorphisms is wrong or that I'm missing something.  Does what I'm doing seem legit?

Answer (score 1):

Observe that since $\;|\gamma|=1\;$ , we then have that $\;\gamma^{-1}=\overline\gamma\;$ , so in fact

$$\gamma+\gamma^{-1}=2\text{Re}\,\gamma=2\cos\frac{2\pi}n$$

Thus, $\;\Bbb Q(\gamma+\gamma^{-1})\subset \Bbb R\;$ and you're looking then for automorphisms fixing this. Can you now complete the exercise? (Further hint: if $\;z\in\Bbb C\;$ , then in fact $\;z\in\Bbb R\iff...\;$ what?)

Comment: It would have to be a real number.  That is, the imaginary part of it is zero.  If an automorphism is to preserve this, it needs to be a specific type of rotation of the vector.

Comment: @NinosławCiszewski Almost correct. In fact, a reflection. Which one leaves real numbers fixed?

Comment: I see, so it will be the complex conjugation, which leaves real numbers fixed.  But where does that reside in my Galois group?  Which is isomorphic to is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$?  I was under the impression that all the elements there are rotations.

Comment: The elements of the Galois group are never rotations.